# Código Java Script no funciona si es que no se encuentra dentro del Documento HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3, web

Este es el docuemtno HTML donde esta enlazado el codigo Java Script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/StyleIndex.css">
    <script src="../JS/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>


<body>

    <!-- SIDMENU COMPLETO -->
    <div id="sidemenu" class="menu-collapsed">

    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div id="header">

        <div id="title"> <span>Navegación</span> </div>

        <!-- boton para colapsar y expandir -->
        <div id="menu-btn">
            <img src="../icons/menu.png" height="20px" alt="">  
        </div>
    </div>


    <!--ITEMS-->

    <div id="menu-items">

        <div class="item">
            <a href="">
                <div class="icon"><img src="../icons/man.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="title">Caballero</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a href="">
                <div class="icon"><img src="../icons/man.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="title">Caballero</div>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Y este es mi código de JavaScript.

```
/*Creamos dos variables*/

/*este apuntara al boton del menu-btn */
const btn = document.querySelector('#menu-btn');


/**este aputara a todo el menu */
const menu = document.querySelector('#sidemenu');

/**Agregamos un evento para el boton del menu */
btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    menu.classList.toggle("menu-expanded");
    menu.classList.toggle("menu-collapsed");

 /**Esta setencia es para que el body se desplace a la derecha y no tape */           
    document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('body-expanded');
});
```

Como mencione, si el código Java Script se encuentra fuera del documento html no funciona y me sale el sigueinte error en la consola:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

Pero si el codigo java script se encuentra dentro del documento html todo funciona bien sin problemas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/StyleIndex.css">
    <script></script>
</head>


<body>

    <!-- SIDMENU COMPLETO -->
    <div id="sidemenu" class="menu-collapsed">

    <!-- HEADER -->
    <div id="header">

        <div id="title"> <span>Navegación</span> </div>

        <!-- boton para colapsar y expandir -->
        <div id="menu-btn">
            <img src="../icons/menu.png" height="20px" alt="">  
        </div>
    </div>


    <!--ITEMS-->

    <div id="menu-items">

        <div class="item">
            <a href="">
                <div class="icon"><img src="../icons/man.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="title">Caballero</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <a href="">
                <div class="icon"><img src="../icons/man.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="title">Caballero</div>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
   </div>


   <!-- 

AQUI EMPIEZA EL SCRIPT

    -->
   <script>      
      /*Creamos dos variables*/

/*este apuntara al boton del menu-btn */
const btn = document.querySelector('#menu-btn');


/**este aputara a todo el menu */
const menu = document.querySelector('#sidemenu');

/**Agregamos un evento para el boton del menu */
btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    menu.classList.toggle("menu-expanded");
    menu.classList.toggle("menu-collapsed");

 /**Esta setencia es para que el body se desplace a la derecha y no tape */           
    document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('body-expanded');
});
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

¿A que se debe todo esto?

Answer (score 1):

Debes colocar el llamado al script al final del body, si lo haces arriba el navegador trata de correr el código sin antes haber creado el DOM completo y entonces no lo puede utilizar ni cambiar ni nada porque aún no existe. Recuerda que es todo en cascada, de arriba hacia abajo.